# How to pass custom template tags to Jinja2 Template class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

For example, I attached Jinja2 to my pythonic project with the next code ([Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/#basic-api-usage)):

```
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template(text_of_the_template)
template.render(**kwargs)
```

The example of using a custom template tag (from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pocoo-libs/YscFKoSlLpE)):

```
 from jinja2 import contextfunction

 @contextfunction
 def widget(context, template_name, **extra_context):
     t = jinja_env.get_template('widgets/' + template_name)
     ctx = dict(context.items())
     ctx.update(extra_context)
     return t.render(ctx)

 jinja_env.globals['widget'] = widget

# And then in the template:

{{ widget('last_tweets.html') }}
```

How to bind Jinja2 environment and the code above (the Template class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `jinja2.Template()` to get your template you should get it through the environment.

So you will get something like this instead:

```
template = jinja_env.from_string(text_of_the_template)
template.render(**kwargs)
```

Here's the dos: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment.from_string